# flutter_quill and saving data in firestore as JSON

Tags: flutter, firebase

I use [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) rich text editor in app.I want to save JSON data in firebase.
how can i do that?.

after converting document as JSON,how can i save it to firebase?

```
var json = jsonEncode(_controller.document.toDelta().toJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a string object, you can save it as a string?